# PayPal recurring payments - primary payment method

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

We've just implemented and are in the process of testing using Express Checkout with PayPal. Subscriptions/recurring payments are our primary source of income.

We've just noticed that the 'primary payment method' for new recurring payment profiles using the Express Checkout method is always 'PayPal balance', even if they specified their credit card in the checkout process.

We are processing the initial payment ourselves as part of the same checkout procedure, so that perhaps could be interfering with the funding payment method selection as their selection might be applied to the first payment and not the recurring payment profile.

When testing (in production mode) we're selecting credit card as the payment method but the recurring payment profile is being set up with their paypal balance as the primary method with no backup method.

We are processing the initial transaction first (via the 'DoExpressCheckoutPayment' method) then creating the recurring payment profile (via the 'CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile' method).

Is their any way we can guarantee their selection carries across to their recurring payment profile, or is there something we're doing wrong?

I'm assuming that having credit card as the primary payment method would be much more successful.

I've tried to contact PayPal but haven't heard back as yet.